# special closing method for tooltipster

Tags: javascript, tooltipster

I want the tooltipster-toolstip closed after 12 seconds in the normal case (and have defined the options for that,) but if a user clicks into the tooltip he should be able to stop the closing process. Then tolltip should stay there twice the time or can be closed by clicking a cross in the roght corner (like you can do it now also). I set interactive: true, but that did not stop the closing-process after 12000 ms.

```
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                             plugins: ['sideTip', 'scrollableTip'],
                             position: 'bottom',
                             contentAsHTML: true,
                             animation: 'grow',
                             interactive: true,
                             delay: 400,
                             interactive: true,
                             trigger: (prev == 1) ? 'hover' : 'click',
                             timer: 12000
                           });
```

I've got no experience with implementing this custom behavior. Could anybody help? Kind regards Peter